# Delphi: Win7 side effect with forms

Tags: delphi, windows-7, ide, autosuggest

Win7/x64, Delphi 6 Prof.

Win7 drives me crazy with his side effect. I describe it:

When I force the suggestion with Ctrl+Space, or Delphi do this automatically, the Delphi don't show the suggestion dropdown listbox, he is only bring my all opened forms to front, one by one.

This causes that what I typing is not going to editor window: it is going to any property of the active form, of the active control.

For example.

Ctrl+Space+"ShowMes..."

I don't got ShowMessage with suggestion listbox, I type ShowMess into my main form's caption.

Many times I need to make update pack's because the buttons, caption, etc got "ShowMes" or "Excep" or other property, because I type into these windows...

This function is sometimes broken on win7.

May I can restore the normal working mode without "bring all opened form to front"?

Thanks:
   dd

Comment: Delphi 6 pre-dates UAC and commits the faux pas of writing to the program files directory. Even before UAC was introduced this is most definitely very bad practice, but UAC brings such errors in closer focus. Have you installed and configured your Delphi 6 setup to tackle this issue?

Comment: I installed Delphi 6 into c:\Delphi6 directory.

Comment: you should consider installing D6 into a Windows XP VM rather than wasting productivity time tackling within W7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable UAC in Windows 7, see here:
http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm

Also running Delphi 6 in Windows XP compatibility mode should do the trick.
See this discussion on the embarcadero forums, it's about Delphi 7, but it's the same issue:
https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=204928&tstart=0

Finally see here how to run a program in XP compatibility mode:
See: http://www.w7forums.com/application-compatibility-mode-t314.html
Or: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html